# How to exclude lines matching a regex pattern in a column by awk?

Tags: awk

I want to exclude lines containing a specific string.

```
header
1:test
2:test
3:none
4:test
```

Why don't these commands work?

```
awk -F: 'FNR>1 {$0 !~ /none/} {print $1}' 1.txt
awk -F: 'FNR>1 {$2 !~ /none/} {print $1}' 1.txt
```

but this works:

```
awk '$0 !~ /none/ {print $0}' 1.txt
```

I intend to get

```
1
2
4
```

Comment: Use `awk -F: 'NR>1 && !/none/{print $1}' file` or `awk -F: 'NR>1 && $2 !~ /none/{print $1}' file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works beautifully!

Comment: Closer to what you were trying to do (but not better than the Correct Answer you selected): First, you have two independent actions listed. No matter what the first one does, the second will be executed. And your first "action" is not an action at all. What you meant to do is an `if` statement, but you didn't write it as an `if` statement. You could do it that way; but the usual way is as Wiktor showed you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the regex test as condition, not as action, and may use

```
awk -F: 'FNR>1 && !/none/{print $1}' file
awk -F: 'FNR>1 && $2 !~ /none/{print $1}' file
```

See an [awk online demo](https://ideone.com/mG9p8V)

**Details**

- `-F:` - sets the field separator to a colon
- `FNR>1 && !/none/` - if number of processed records for current file is more than 1 and there is no `none` on the line (if `$2 !~ /none/` is used, returns true if Field 2 does not contain `none` pattern)
- `{print $1}` - print Field 1 value.